# Azure functions - .NET playwright

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, playwright

We have an Azure function on a Cron trigger that runs once a day.
In this trigger we would like to use the .NET Playwright library to scrape a webpage.

We are running this Azure function V4 in Dotnet-isolated mode on windows.
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH is set to D:\DWASFiles\Sites**\VirtualDirectory0\Browsers

On startup the powershell installation script is ran to install chrome with OS dependencies.

Our logs show:
Get-WmiObject : No such interface supported
At C:\home\site\wwwroot.playwright\package\bin\install_media_pack.ps1:1

- $osInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedA
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Pow
  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\DWASFiles\Sites#1teamleader-synchronizer-test\VirtualDirectory0\Browsers'

I have also tried installing the browsers in the release pipeline and including them in the folder to publish. This requires a different path for PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH.

Except playwright then throws: (Executable doesn't exist at C:\home\site\wwwroot.playwright\package.local-browsers\chromium-1084\chrome-win\chrome.exe). When checking through kudu the exe does exist in this location.

Is there a guide to running .NET playwright on Azure functions, if so what am i missing?